# I'm trying to write a fixture using the association using labels feature.

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I keep getting the output that it's taking the name and processing it literally. I've also tried treating it as a polymorphic association and that didn't help. Any thoughts?
My fixtures are here: http://pastie.org/private/smo0ewjkto2s4yxdvhy54a

Answer (score 1):

So I changed my foreign key in the database, but I forgot to update my code. That solved it.